# Multiple EyeFinity Display groups

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, eyefinity, amd-firepro

Is it possible with an EyeFinity enabled card to make multiple display groups at once? I was playing with a FirePro 2460 and while a 4x1 or 2x2 display group works quite nicely, if I make a 2x1 display group and then select one of the other displays to try to make a second 2x1 display group, it disables the first one.  Is there any way to circumvent this behavior and set up two separate spans on the same card?

Additionally, can you set up distinct display groups if they're on different cards?  I will have the opportunity to test several of these cards in one machine very shortly, but I'm curious if anyone has any experience.  EDIT: I can confirm that you can make multiple spans on multiple cards (as long as they don't cross cards, obviously)

(If the answers are different for FirePro/FireMV cards and Radeon cards, that is helpful and relevant knowledge - I doubt it, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'm going to say "There's no way to do this".  I've only been looking for almost a year now. :)

Comment: I can confirm this on my AMD W600, it appears to be impossible to simply make 2 Eyefinity group working at the same time.
However there is a hack : If you have 2 GPU, you can configure 2 groups, one on each GPU, then shut down the PC, take the 2nd GPU out, plug back the monitors of the 2nd GPU on the first and restart.
It kinda "works".
I'm still waiting on AMD to take notice of my tickets on the matter (1 year and counting..)

Answer (score 0):

Is possibile to create multiple eyefinity group in only one pc, But you need more Than one GPU card. The furetto eyefinity group can be done in the first GPU. The other eyefinity must be setup to the second GPU card.